# Is a locally free sheaf of finite rank a projective object?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a locally ringed space, in the category of $\mathscr O_X$- modules, is a locally free sheaf of finite rank a projective object?

Comment: What is true (almost trivially) is that it's "internally projective": if $\mathscr{E}$ is locally free and $\mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{F}''$ is epimorphic, then $\mathscr{Hom}(\mathscr{E}, \mathscr{F}) \to \mathscr{Hom}(\mathscr{E}, \mathscr{F}''$ is also epimorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = \mathbb{P}^1$. Following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225657/representations-of-a-quiver-and-sheaves-on-p1), it is easy to show that the structure sheaf $\mathscr{O}$ is not projective. Indeed, Serre duality implies $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathscr{O}, \omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}) \cong H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathscr{O})^\vee \neq 0$.

You can avoid Serre duality with a longer argument given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319382/hartshorne-exercise-iii-6-2-b-mathfrakqcox-need-not-have-enough-proje?noredirect=1&lq=1).